# How to enable OpenSSL support in an alternate install of Python 2.5.1?

Tags: python, openssl, importerror

Some background info:
I'm trying to run a server program in `python 2.5.1` (the version the server was written for and tested on). The program needs the OpenSSL library for some of its functions. I installed python 2.5.1 from source as the yum repository for the Amazon Linux instance I'm running on does not have the version of python I need.

When I try to run the server with python 2.5.1 I get the following import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
ImportError: No module named OpenSSL
```

I know that the OpenSSL libraries are installed as I can import them into Python 2.6 (the version of python installed by yum). It's just that my python 2.5.1 installation can't see them.

I have also installed pyOpenSSL via yum with no luck.

Comment: Did you tried to append path from Python 2.6?

Comment: You need to compile pyOpenSSL against Python 2.5 ([see here](http://packages.python.org/pyOpenSSL/building-unix.html)). Appending the Python 2.6 path won't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

installed python libraries are specific to a particular version.  so the pyOpenSSL you installed from yum will be for the system python.  you need to install a separate instance of pyOpenSSL for the alt-installed 2.5 python.

if you use python2.5 to install distutils then you'll find that you have an `easy_install-2.5` that you can use: `easy_install-2.5 pyopenssl` (or similar).  but note that may also install a new version of `easy_install`, overwriting the existing one for the system python (if you have one).  to use distutils with the existing package use `easy_install-2.7` (if it's python 2.7).

does that make sense?  basically, each python is distinct and needs its own set of libraries.  in contrast, easy_install is installed globally, but there is a version-specific copy of easy_install for each python...!

if you want to avoid the mess with easy_install, you can use virtualenv.  create a new environment for 2.5, enable that, and you can install the pyopenssl in there (using the easy_install from the environment).  that may sound more complicated if you've never ysed virtualenv, but if you give it a little time to understand it will likely work out better in the long-term.